# Get text from EditTextPreference and save it

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am trying to build a settings menu, but I'm having some troubles...

1. I cant get the text from `EditTextPreference`
2. I cant insert it on my `sharedPreferences` file

Can I have some help?

**Prefs Class**

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    contact1 = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("contact1");
    editor.putString("contact1", String.valueOf(contact1)).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

**Prefs XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Contact 1"
    android:key="@+id/contact1"
    android:summary="Enter your contact">
</EditTextPreference>

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Contact 2"
    android:key="@+id/contact2"
    android:summary="Enter your contact">
</EditTextPreference>
```

**Get data on main activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings =          PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    number1 = settings.getString("contact1", "");
    number2 = settings.getString("contact2", "");
    contact1 = "tel: " + number1;
    contact2 = "tel: " + number2;
```

Comment: Did you extend "PreferenceActivity" to your settings activity?

Comment: Yes I used... And also an Implements

Comment: Can you add all other code segments relevant to this process? ex: settings.xml

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Done... I can open the settings menu, click on the boxs, but when I edit some text it dosent save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these way...

```
public class AdvancePreferenceExample extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private static final String KEY_EDIT_TEXT_PREFERENCE = "name";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        updatePreference(KEY_EDIT_TEXT_PREFERENCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        updatePreference(key);
    }

    private void updatePreference(String key){
        if (key.equals(KEY_EDIT_TEXT_PREFERENCE)){
            Preference preference = findPreference(key);
            if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference){
                EditTextPreference editTextPreference =  (EditTextPreference)preference;
                if (editTextPreference.getText().trim().length() > 0){
                    editTextPreference.setSummary("Entered Name is  " + editTextPreference.getText());
                }else{
                    editTextPreference.setSummary("Enter Your Name");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[here is sample](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/edittext-preference/)

Comment: Have been searching a bit more... And the problem might not be on my Preferences class, but when I try to import the shared preferences values... I have edited the post